# Can a hydrogen atom sit still?

Tags: atoms

Can we take a single lone hydrogen atom (proton and electron?) and set it in one place and observe it staying there?

How about just a proton?

A neutron?

How about just an electron?

Comment: You can "freeze" molecules in place using laser cooling techniques. But you cannot perfectly localise them due to Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In liquid helium, there is a [phonon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon) resonance with temperature around 11 K that has the same energy and momentum as a cold neutron with wavelength around 9 Å. Neutrons with this wavelength (which have a speed of a few hundred meters per second) essentially undergo a "billiard ball collision" with a phonon and stop. Since liquid helium (with boiling point around 4 K) doesn't contain much background of 11 K phonons to scatter the neutrons back up, you can produce quite a population of "stopped" neutrons. They're technically called [ultracold neutrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultracold_Neutrons) since they don't *quite* stop: the typical leftover velocity is 5–10 m/s, slower than a good human sprinter.

Answer (score 0):

At least for spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particles like protons and electrons this is not possible. A phenomenon called [zitterbewegung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zitterbewegung) is responsible for rapid motion of these particles. The frequency of these motions can be as high as $10^{21}$ hertz.